# Ensembling regression models

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, ensemble-learning

I'm working on a securities pricing project and have a bunch of models I'd like to stack/ensemble together.  I've been using simple linear regression in R (the `lm()` function) so far but the results are over fitting pretty badly.

Does anyone have any suggestions for whether some other stacking method might be better or any papers/articles that describe how to stack regression models (as opposed to classification models).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are experiencing over fitting you could look into [regularized regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_%28mathematics%29) which in R can be fit using many packages such as ([glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html)). There are many good tutorials for this - one is [Regularization Paths for Generalized Linear Models
via Coordinate Descent](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v33/i01/paper)

You might also look at `randomForest` or `gbm` in R depending on your data.

You can try fitting many models and averaging their prediction as well (your reference to ensembles).